# AWS SAM HttpApi - internal server error when adding lambda auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I've declared an HttpApi and a simple hello world function using AWS SAM template and it's working, I'm trying to add a lambda request authorizer now but I'm getting internal server error when testing it using Postman.
If I remove the required header "tokenID" the response is

```
 {
"message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

if I add it:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

also, the access logs headers are empty, for example: BVharit1liAEMrw=: (-) -

Template:

```
Parameters:
  StageName:
    Type: String
    Default: Prod

Resources:
  HttpApiFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world
      Handler: hello-world/app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        ExplicitApi:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref HttpApi
            Method: GET
            Path: /
            TimeoutInMillis: 15000
            PayloadFormatVersion: "2.0"

  AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: Auth
      Handler: Auth/auth.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x

  AccessLogs:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup

  HttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      CorsConfiguration:
        AllowHeaders:
          - tokenID
        AllowMethods:
          - GET
        AllowOrigins:
          - '*'
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: 'FirebaseAuth'
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuth:
            FunctionInvokeRole: !GetAtt AuthFunctionRole.Arn
            EnableSimpleResponses: true
            AuthorizerPayloadFormatVersion: 2.0
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthFunction.Arn
            Identity:
              Headers:
                - tokenID
      StageName: !Ref StageName
      AccessLogSettings:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt AccessLogs.Arn
        Format: '$context.extendedRequestId: ($context.integrationErrorMessage) $event.headers'
```

Lambda request authorizer:

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    return {
        "isAuthorized": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda authorizer is not returning what is expected to be an actual lambda authorizer (an IAM policy).  This is why you get that internal error when you turn it on.

To fix, replace is with something like this that returns an IAM policy (or rejects):

```
// A simple token-based authorizer example to demonstrate how to use an authorization token 
// to allow or deny a request. In this example, the caller named 'user' is allowed to invoke 
// a request if the client-supplied token value is 'allow'. The caller is not allowed to invoke 
// the request if the token value is 'deny'. If the token value is 'unauthorized' or an empty
// string, the authorizer function returns an HTTP 401 status code. For any other token value, 
// the authorizer returns an HTTP 500 status code. 
// Note that token values are case-sensitive.

exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
    var token = event.authorizationToken;
    // modify switch statement here to your needs
    switch (token) {
        case 'allow':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'deny':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'unauthorized':
            callback("Unauthorized");   // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
            break;
        default:
            callback("Error: Invalid token"); // Return a 500 Invalid token response
    }
};

// Help function to generate an IAM policy
var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    var authResponse = {};
    
    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        var policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        var statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; 
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }
    
    // Optional output with custom properties of the String, Number or Boolean type.
    authResponse.context = {
        "stringKey": "stringval",
        "numberKey": 123,
        "booleanKey": true
    };
    return authResponse;
}
```

Lots more information here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-lambda-function-create

Comment: I have tried this and still gives me 500 internal error... I think that is for REST APIs. The question was using HTTP APIs which has the option to return simple boolean response return { "isAuthorized": true }

Comment: @xanderlopez did you create a callback method?  if so, try searching or creating a question that has the error message you get.